# OnColumnChanged and OnRowChanged events to TStringGrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I need to know when the row/column property of a grid was changed in order to do some processing. 
In TStringGrid Row property is

> ```
> property Row: Longint read FCurrent.Y write SetRow;
> ```

But, unfortunately I cannot override the SetRow as it is private. SelectCell is not private BUT it is called BEFORE the new column and row attribute is set. The only solution will be to replace all calls to Row property with my own property

> ```
> property MyRow: Longint read Row write SetMyRow;
> ```

but it is not the most elegant solution. 
Any ideas?

---

Delphi 7, Win 7 32 bit

Comment: DelphiXE has an onSelectCell event which does just this.  Unfortunately I do not have Delphi 7 available to verify if it was available in that version or not.

Comment: TStringGrid has an OnSelectCell event in all Delphi versions, AFAIK.

Comment: @Remy: Indeed. For one thing, it would be very strange if not. Second, when was this component last updated? It really has the old Win 9x look...

Comment: @Andreas: TStringGrid is a custom-made control, not a wrapper for any OS control.  It is completely custom-drawn, and the drawing logic was never updated to account for theming.

Comment: @Remy: Yes, of course I know that. That is also what I meant. If the control would have been actively developed, it wouldn't look so odd in a modern Windows environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had a look at the source of `TStringGrid`. The `Row` property is inherited from `TCustomGrid` (via `TDrawGrid` and `TCustomDrawGrid`), where it is defined as

```
property Row: Longint read FCurrent.Y write SetRow;
```

as you say. `SetRow` calls `FocusCell` whichs calls `MoveCurrent`. This one calls  `SelectCell`. This is a virtual function, and although it is highly trivial in `TCustomGrid`, where it is defined as

```
function TCustomGrid.SelectCell(ACol, ARow: Longint): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
end;
```

in `TCustomDrawGrid`, we have

```
function TCustomDrawGrid.SelectCell(ACol, ARow: Longint): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  if Assigned(FOnSelectCell) then FOnSelectCell(Self, ACol, ARow, Result);
end;
```

Hence, `OnSelectCell` is called every time `Row` or `Col` is changed, as Skamradt wrote in a comment.

Yes, this event is called before the new cell is selected, but we have

```
FOnSelectCell: TSelectCellEvent;
```

where

```
type
  TSelectCellEvent = procedure (Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Longint;
var CanSelect: Boolean) of object;
```

`ACol` and `ARow` contain the new "values-to-be". You can even disallow the change of selected cell by setting `CanSelect` to `false`. Consequently, there is no need to override anything.

(Also, you cannot override `SetRow` because it is not **virtual**. It is very possible to override private and protected members, but only virtual methods can be overridden.)